# Is there a way to check if an sms message is successfully sent programmatically in j2me

Tags: java-me, sms, wma

I have a simple j2me application that send sms to a certain cell no and then erase a certain record once it succeed. But sometimes it fails due to several reasons like network, battery, etc. Is there a way to validate if an sms message is successfully sent?

Thanks,
czetsuya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a try catch on the code that will send an sms, if an exception is thrown then an error occured, else the message is sent successfully, so if you didn't got an error than it is sent successfully

You can check it in the example below:

```
boolean sent = false
try {
   //send the message
   sent = true;
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   sent = false;
}
if (sent) {
    //your message has been sent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if this line is successfully executed in [this](http://freecode-freecode.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-send-sms-in-j2me.html) example then it must be sent else exception would be thrown

```
 smsconn.send(txtmessage)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. Actually that's what I'm doing enclosing the method send() with try/catch block. But it seems it was not able to catch when the message sending page in a series of sms. It's because the program can send 5 sms in a row.

Comment: return boolean flag false from your method if exception s thrown you can not determine it later